# Groovy List of List

Tags: groovy, apache-camel

I have a Camel app that returns records from a database. When I output the Camel ${body} I see:

```
[
  {sku=HT-0001, Performance=Fair, ProductGroup=Movers, name=ProductPerformance}, 
  {sku=HT-0002, Performance=Great for product group, ProductGroup=Staid, name=ProductPerformance}, 
  {sku=VT-KK2150, Performance= act7, ProductGroup=Slammers, name=ProductPerformance}
]
```

I would like to build a data structure for those values in Groovy. I am assuming I am dealing with a list of lists given the structure displayed above. Not sure what other type of structure it might be.

Just looking for opinions as regards if this is indeed a list of lists and if so, how best to write sample Groovy code to represent those values.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out ...I believe Camel is returning a list of Maps and can be simulated locally as:

```
def y = [
  ['sku':'VT-KK2150', 'Performance':'act7', 'ProductGroup':'Jammers', 'name':'ProductPerformance1'],
  ['sku':'VT-LL2150', 'Performance':'act8', 'ProductGroup':'Sammers', 'name':'ProductPerformance2'],
  ['sku':'VT-MM2150', 'Performance':'act9', 'ProductGroup':'Bammers', 'name':'ProductPerformance3'], 
]
```